# How do I get my bot to send a message when it is added to a guild? - discord.py

Tags: discord.py, bots

I want my bot to send a message to a specific guild channel whenever it is added or removed from any guild. How do I make it in Discord.py? I am aware of client.event but I am unsure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

My bots code (sends to channel at the top of server where it has permissions)

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
  for channel in guild.text_channels:
    if channel.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages:
      embedHi = discord.Embed(
                title="Thanks for adding me!",
                description=
                f"<:impostor:774673531786625024>I am the Impostor - a bot created by Baz!<:impostor:774673531786625024>\n\n<:noice:751384305464377375>You can join my support server by running $help and you can view all of my commands here as well!<:noice:751384305464377375>\n\n<:patreon:839897502925062165> Feel free to go to https://www.patreon.com/theimpostor to gain access to cool premium commands! <:patreon:839897502925062165>\nIf you join the <:purple:839879572631453696> Hacker Plan <:purple:839879572631453696>, then you will recieve all premium commands, a special role, early access to commands and even work in progress updates!\n:partying_face:Have fun!:partying_face:\n\n\n<:ping:757276110252670986>When you added this bot, it was in version {__version__}<:ping:757276110252670986>",
          url="https://www.patreon.com/theimpostor",
                colour=discord.Colour.red())
      embedHi.set_thumbnail(
                url=
                "image url"
            )
      embedHi.set_image(url="image url")
      embedHi.set_footer(
                text="© Baz - The Impostor - Among Us bot for Discord")
      await channel.send(embed=embedHi)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    # send your message
```

[Relevant docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_guild_join#discord.on_guild_join)